# Error parsing date in parametrized query in java

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to prevent SQL injection and I have converted this raw insert query:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
String sql = "insert into customer (cust_id, cust_name, father_name, birth_date, CNIC, city, card_num, acc_num, bank_name, address, email, ph_num) values ( " + String.valueOf(txtcust_id.getText()) + ",'" + txtcust_name.getText()
+ "','" + txtf_name.getText() + "','" + txtb_date.getText() + "','" + txtcnic.getText() + "','" + txtcity.getText() + "','" + txtcard_num.getText() + "','" + txtacc_num.getText() + "','" + txtb_n.getText() + "','" + txtadd.getText() + "','" + txtemail.getText()+ "','" + txtph_num.getText() + "' )"; 

//stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 

int rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 

String msg = "Insert Query Execution Failed"; if(rowsAffected > 0){   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Query Successful"); } 
else { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg, "Execution Alert",         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

I have converted this into a parameterized query, like so:

```
System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "insert into customer (cust_id, cust_name, father_name, birth_date, CNIC, city, card_num, acc_num, bank_name, address, email, ph_num) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txtcust_id1.getText()));
stmt.setString(2, txtcust_name1.getText());
stmt.setString(3, txtf_name1.getText());
stmt.setDate(4, sqlDateDOB);
stmt.setLong(5, Integer.parseInt(txtcnic1.getText()));
stmt.setString(6, txtcity1.getText() );
stmt.setLong(7, Integer.parseInt(txtcard_num1.getText()));
stmt.setLong(8, Integer.parseInt(txtacc_num1.getText()));
stmt.setString(9, txtb_n1.getText());
stmt.setString(11, txtadd1.getText());
stmt.setString(12, txtemail1.getText());
stmt.setInt(13, Integer.parseInt(txtph_num1.getText()));

//stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
String msg = "Insert Query Execution Failed";
if(rows > 0) {
    msg = "Insert Query Executed Successfully";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg, "Execution Alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

The problem I am having is with `setDate`. My data is formated as `yyyy,mm,dd`.  The `sqlDateDOB` variable is defined like so:

```
String str = txtb_date.getText(); //must not be empty text!
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MM,dd");
java.sql.Date sqlDateDOB = new java.sql.Date(fmt.parse(str).getTime());
```

Comment: I slightly rephrased your question, hopefully so that it is clearer, feel free to correct it if I've made a mistake.  Please also provide more detail as to what problem you are having; are you seeing an exception? Is the wrong data being inserted?  The more context you can provide, the more helpful we can be.

Comment: what is `sqlDateDOB`, what's its value? (NB: there's no format involved `setDate` is expecting a `Date` object)

Comment: String str = txtb_date.getText();//must not be empty text !
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MM,dd");
java.sql.Date sqlDateDOB = new java.sql.Date(fmt.parse(str).getTime());

Comment: @dimo414 its not inserting anything but gives an error that says java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""

Comment: As stated by the exception you get, `""` is not a valid date.

Comment: @RC i insert a correct date in the textfield, it still gives this error.

Comment: @SamarQureshi please include code snippets in your question, they're hard to read in comments.  Please also post the exact exception you're getting (in the question) and indicate which line it's occurring on.  My guess is it's happening on the line where you define `sqlDateDOB`, because `str` is, in fact, empty.

Comment: You must print out the value returned by `txtb_date.getText()` to _prove_ it is not empty. Otherwise, all evidence suggests it is, in fact, empty regardless of what you believe.

Comment: You will get better results from your own debugging and from posting here if you strip your code down to bare minimum to demonstrate the problem. See: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).